# node id for export blocks

Tags: blocks, importing-exporting

I have a webform node and I want to export it (via node export) to other sites - the issue is when the node id is already assigned drupal assigns a new id.

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('webform','block_view','client-block-5');
print $block['content'];
?>
<?php print render(block_get_blocks_by_region(''));?>
```

So the code does not work as the id is **client-block-9**, apart from creating a region for this block is there a work around?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to make this reusable or is this a one time operation?

Comment: it's a one time operation but trying to keep it as flexible as possible. Idea;;y if they all had the same id the process would be much easier.

Comment: The other option I think of is to use UUID or a field that holds an identifier. And in your block you need to fetch the node that has the value X in your identifier field instead. Once you have the node id you can replace client-block-5 with client-block-[fetched nid]